# What is the meaning of the math expression with a polygon expressed by linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

given a set of points(0, 1), (0, 6), (4, 10), (8, 10), (11, 7), (11, 4), (7, 0), and (1, 0).

I have attached the polygon consisting of these points, and I express the region as {x|$a_{i}^{T}x \le b_{i}$}, where A = $[a_{1},a_{2},a_{3},a_{4},a_{5},a_{6},a_{7},a_{8}]$=$$\left[\begin{matrix} 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & -1 & -1\\0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1&1&1&1\\\end{matrix} \right]$$

b = $$\left[\begin{matrix} 11&0&10&0&1&18&6&-7\end{matrix} \right]^{T}$$

so can anybody explain what $\frac{a_{i}^{T}y-b_{i}}{\sqrt{a_{i}^{T}a_{i}}}$ stands for in details? Here, y is a 2-dimensional vector standing for a point inside the polygon region. I am not familiar with matrix expression.

Comment: You seem to have several sign errors in $A$. The 2nd col should be -1,0 corresponding to $x\ge0$. The 3rd col should be $0,-1$ corresponding to $y\ge0$. The 5th col should be -1,-1, and the corresponding entry in $b$ should be -1, to give $x+y\ge1$ and ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vector $a_i=\binom{a_{i1}}{a_{i2}}$ being a column vector, $a_{i}^{T}y$ is the product of a row vector $a_i^T$ and a column vector $y=\binom{u}{v}$, thus a dot product $a_{i1}u+a_{i2}v$.

For similar reasons, $a_{i}^{T}a_{i}$ is the squared norm $n^2$ of vector $a_i$.

As a consequence :

$$\frac{a_{i}^{T}y-b_{i}}{\sqrt{a_{i}^{T}a_{i}}}=\underbrace{\dfrac{a_{i1}u+a_{i2}v-b_i}{n}}_{E}$$

which can be interpreted as

> the distance of point $y=\binom{u}{v}$ to the straight line with equation $E=0$.

Remark : Equation $E=0$ is called a **normalized equation** of a straight line.
(see "Normalized equation" in https://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Calculus/StraightLine.shtml and the reference herein to "distance from a point to a line").

Comment: A precision : it is a signed distance. Take the absolute value if you want a "true distance".